# Language tabs in content editor

Tags: joomla-3.x, multilingual, editor

Does anybody know any plugin for Joomla 3.x to switch between languages(ex. tabs) while editing content? You need to create pages with different languages and after that create dependencies between them by default. It takes too much time.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried FaLang? 
FaLang is a (free) component for Joomla (2.x and 3.x) and is built on the base of JoomFish (which doesn't have any development anymore on J3.x).

With FaLang you are able to translate the content, categories, menu-items of Joomla without the need to duplicate the contents.
Even for some components as HikaShop, K2, jDownload and many others they made it possible to translate it.

It works like this: You create an article in your base language. If you have a paid version of FaLang, you can edit the content right after saving in the same view. Otherwise, you'll need to go to the FaLang component where you can edit the other languages.

For more details about FaLang: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/languages/multi-lingual-content/falang

If you want a video about the plugin and how it exactly works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yT8PkNKoTeE
In this video they use J2.x, but it is roughly the same as in 3.x.

Comment: Hello Robin... congrats for getting involved and tried to answer the OPs question... However keep in mind: Good (and acceptable) answers must be more than a link to an external site, resource, software. You should try to explain what the plugin does and how it could provide what the OP is asking. Please read the [answer] section of the website

Comment: Hi @FFrewin, my apologies I'll edit my answer. You are right, I was too fast with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This was not possible. Each article has a differente ID and differente settings. You need chose how language this article ID will be displayed.

[image]

Comment: Actually it's possible to write an extension to do that, but it will take a lot of time, that's why I'm asking.